# Regular Expressions data clearance using regex serials in R

Tags: r, regex

A list of keywords contains Chinese Characters and English Words, just like below:

```
[1] "    服务 接口   知识 组织   开放 查询   语义 推理   Web   服务 "                                                                        
[2] "    Solr   分面 搜索   标准 信息管理 "  
[3] "  语义   Ｗ ｉ ｋ ｉ   标注   导航   检索   Ｓ ｅ ｍ ａ ｎ ｔ ｉ ｃ Ｍ ｅ ｄ ｉ ａ Ｗ ｉ ｋ ｉ   Ｐ Ａ Ｕ Ｘ   Ｉ ｋ ｅ Ｗ ｉ ｋ ｉ    "
[4] "  Liferay   主从 模式   集成 知识 平台    " 
[5] "    数据 摄取   SKE   本体   属性 映射   三元组 存储    "
```

Some of English Words has space between each character(such as the 3rd row), “`Ｗ ｉ ｋ ｉ`”, “`Ｓ ｅ ｍ ａ ｎ ｔ ｉ ｃ Ｍ ｅ ｄ ｉ ａ Ｗ ｉ ｋ ｉ`”, “`Ｐ Ａ Ｕ Ｘ`”, “`Ｉ ｋ ｅ Ｗ ｉ ｋ ｉ`”. Among these words, there are more than two space.
Now I am trying to delete the space in these English Words to the results: “`Ｗｉｋｉ`”, “`ＳｅｍａｎｔｉｃＭｅｄｉａＷｉｋｉ`”, “`ＰＡＵＸ`”, “`ＩｋｅＷｉｋｉ`”, and also keep other words like before.
I used “gsub” before like this: “`kwdict<-gsub("^[[:alpha:][:blank:]]+", "\\w", kwdict)`”. But no matter I use "\w" or “[[:alpha:]]”, the results are wrong, all the words have been changed.
How can we choose these English Words accurately and delete the space in it?

```
[1] "    服务 接口   知识 组织   开放 查询   语义 推理   Web   服务 "                                                                        
[2] "    Solr   分面 搜索   标准 信息管理 "                                                                            [3] "  语义   Ｗｉｋｉ   标注   导航   检索   ＳｅｍａｎｔｉｃＭｅｄｉａＷｉｋｉ   ＰＡＵＸ   ＩｋｅＷｉｋｉ    "
[4] "  Liferay   主从 模式   集成 知识 平台    "                                                                         [5] "    数据 摄取   SKE   本体   属性 映射   三元组 存储    "
```

I tried many times using R with these sentences below separately

```
kwdict<-gsub("[[:alpha:]/[:space:]{1}]", "", kwdict)
kwdict<-gsub("[^[:alpha:]_[:space:]]{1}", "", kwdict)
kwdict<-gsub("[^[:alpha:][:space:]]{1}", "", kwdict)
kwdict<-gsub("[^[:alpha:][:space:]{1}^[:alpha:]]", "", kwdict)
kwdict<-gsub("[//>[:space:]{1}]", "", kwdict)
kwdict<-gsub("[[:alpha:][:space:]{1}]", "", kwdict)
```

But it done nothing, delete all the spaces, or even clear all the words! I think that because the pattern include “[:alpha:]” the start mark we used to locate space character. Is there any idea to define this pattern correctly using R?

Comment: `?Encoding` I guess your encoding for the keywords is in bytes, but your gsub is in UTF-8

Comment: Those English words are used in another font, I think is Latin, not English itself. The original PDF docs defined this font, and I never changed it at all. They have no relations with encoding, I am sure about it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to the some of the comments by **@赵鸿丰** and **@waterling**

I think I am able to found the source of your problem, The problem is that those words which you think are english alphabets they are not ascii in nature.They are actually latin upper and lower case of english alphabets. There are however, some of the alphabets are in english("Solar" and "Liferay").

Run the below command to convert this to UTF-8 (You may not need to do this, I am comfortable in seeing things in UTF-8 format and also doing google gives me little better results in terms of UTF-8)

```
string <- c("    服务 接口   知识 组织   开放 查询   语义 推理   Web   服务 ",      
             "    Solr   分面 搜索   标准 信息管理 "  ,
             "  语义   Ｗ ｉ ｋ ｉ   标注   导航   检索   Ｓ ｅ ｍ ａ ｎ ｔ ｉ ｃ Ｍ ｅ ｄ ｉ ａ Ｗ ｉ ｋ ｉ   Ｐ Ａ Ｕ Ｘ   Ｉ ｋ ｅ Ｗ ｉ ｋ ｉ    ",
             "  Liferay   主从 模式   集成 知识 平台    " ,
             "    数据 摄取   SKE   本体   属性 映射   三元组 存储    ")

Encoding(string) <- "UTF-8"
```

Once you run the above command you can see, there are UTF-8 values attached with these characters. I have searched the internet to find what these value translates into. I stumbled upon **[this](http://software.hixie.ch/utilities/cgi/unicode-decoder/character-identifier?keywords=width) site**. These helped me to understand the UTF-8 values associated with it.

So I wrote small regex to solve your problem, I have used `stringr` library. You may choose any library/BASE R **gsub** to solve your problem.

```
value <- str_replace_all(string,'(?<=[\U{FF41}-\U{FF5A}]|[\U{FF21}-\U{FF3A}])\\s*',"")
```

To understand the regex:

The character class(represented in square brackets) contains the UTF range of upper case and lower case LATIN capital letters (which I have found in the site mentioned above). I have put them into regex lookaround assertion along with \s which denotes spaces. I have matched the spaces and then replaced them with nothing. This way, I got your result something like below. I hope this what you are expecting. Also since you can't see this on your console, you can use `str_view_all` function to see these alphabets when translated into html. I have copied and pasted the results from that only.

```
服务 接口 知识 组织 开放 查询 语义 推理 Web 服务
Solr 分面 搜索 标准 信息管理
语义 Ｗｉｋｉ标注 导航 检索 ＳｅｍａｎｔｉｃＭｅｄｉａＷｉｋｉＰＡＵＸＩｋｅＷｉｋｉ
Liferay 主从 模式 集成 知识 平台
数据 摄取 SKE 本体 属性 映射 三元组 存储
```

I hope this explains solution of your problem in detail. Thank you !!!

**After OP's comment**, it seems he want to replace the wide latin english form to normal letters,an external file is used for unicode replacement, this file(NamesList.txt) can be found at **this [link](http://software.hixie.ch/utilities/cgi/unicode-decoder/character-identifier?keywords=width)**

```
library(stringr)
library(Unicode) ##Unicode is a beautiful library having lot of great functions such as u_char_from_name which is used here.
rd_dt <- readLines("NamesList.txt",encoding="UTF-8")

  ##cleaning of Nameslist.txt which has unicode values against wide latin alphabet
rd_dt1 <- rd_dt[grep("[[:alnum:]]{4}\t.*",rd_dt)]

rd_dt1 <- read.delim(textConnection(rd_dt1),sep="\t",stringsAsFactors = F)
rd_dt1 <- rd_dt1[,1:2]
names(rd_dt1) <- c("UTF_8_values","Symbol")
rd_dt1 <- rd_dt1[grep("LATIN",rd_dt1$Symbol),]
rd_dt1 <- rd_dt1[grep("WIDTH",rd_dt1$Symbol),]
value <- substr(rd_dt1$Symbol,nchar(trimws(rd_dt1$Symbol)),nchar(trimws(rd_dt1$Symbol)))
rd_dt1$value <- value
###Assigning captial and small english letter to their corresponding latin wide small and captial letters
letters <-  grepl("CAPITAL",rd_dt1$Symbol)+0
captial_small <- ifelse(letters==1,toupper(rd_dt1$value),tolower(rd_dt1$value))
rd_dt1$capital_small <- captial_small
rd_dt1 <- rd_dt1[,c(1,2,4)]
### From OP's source taking the text which is non english and it is wide latin text
dt <- c('ＳｅｍａｎｔｉｃＭｅｄｉａＷｉｋｉＰＡＵＸＩｋｅＷｉｋｉ')
###Check of the contents between UTF values of OP's text content and the UTF-8 text files
as.u_char(utf8ToInt(dt)) %in% u_char_from_name(rd_dt1$Symbol)
```

#### Final Answer For the conversion:

`paste0(rd_dt1[match(utf8ToInt(dt),u_char_from_name(rd_dt1$Symbol)),"capital_small"],collapse="")`

**Result:**

```
> paste0(rd_dt1[match(utf8ToInt(dt),u_char_from_name(rd_dt1$Symbol)),"capital_small"],collapse="")
[1] "SemanticMediaWikiPAUXIkeWiki"
```

**CAVEAT**: The above code is working well with MACOSX Sierra, and R-3.3 however on windows, automatically on R studio console everything converts into the corresponding english text and I am unable to see the UTF-8 codes against these texts. I am not able to determine the reason.

**EDIT**:

I recently found that there is a function called `stri_trans_general` in `stringi` library which can do this task in much efficient way, once the spaces are removed using regex as mentioned above we can directly translate the latin wide alphabet by using below code:

```
dt <- c('ＳｅｍａｎｔｉｃＭｅｄｉａＷｉｋｉＰＡＵＸＩｋｅＷｉｋｉ')

stringi::stri_trans_general(dt, "latin-ascii")
```

The answer remains the same as mentioned above.

Comment: Thanks for your warmly reply. The 'wide charactor part' could not be changed during regular expression processing. One reason maybe normal regular expression can only cope with normal alphabet set, and these special charactors must transform into normal sets. However, the code list in [link](http://unicode.org/) I'm not sure how to search. What does the search results mean, and how to search the charactor set in this example in that site? Thanks a lot?

Comment: Look it here.http://software.hixie.ch/utilities/cgi/unicode-decoder/character-identifier?keywords=width, i have embed it in my post. Once you change your encoding to utf-8, you have values like(U+FF41 etc for all charcters) search for example U+FF41 (captial letter A) in the above site and put it the regular expression above. I hope this clarifies things.

Comment: also , please note that these are full width character, they seems to be separated with wide gaps and these gaps can't be replaced or removed, Read it here. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Halfwidth_and_fullwidth_forms. so you can replace these charcter with english normal letters using  regex. I have updated my answer little bit

Comment: I download the "Namelist.text" and it's only 1.39M, I am confused that each language has its own alphabet but collect all of them and discript them only use 1.4MB? To search in the document with keyword "wide" is likely to extract all the charactors which discription use "wide", and we also need to look up the "normal" ones to be transfer into. BTW, the program for reading and writing usually occurs strange problems, the one I used to read text file is failed and all I got is each document a warning. I don't known whether this situation will getting better or worse when R3.4.0 launch.

Comment: Thanks for the insights, I am able to clean up the .txt file and finally able to match with your input. You can check the result. Thanks

Comment: I noticed that you use "stringr" as your text analyser, is this library much more stable than those functions in R base or util? I am suffering from "textconnection" and "scan" failure problems while processing mass text documents. Thanks a lot.

Comment: stringr is very good for processing text, and well suited for regeular expression, it is built on top of stringi which is better than stringr, stringr has total of 42 functions whereas stringi has 234. so i believe you should use stringi. It is more user friendly than base R regex, however that i my personal view.

Answer (score 0):

You can solve this problem with two regex, first eliminate the single space between words with:

`s/(\a)\s{1}/\1/g`

Then substitute 2 or more spaces between words with a single space:

`s/\s{2,}/ /g`

Applying these two regex to the following text:

```
T h i s   i s  a   t e s t  c a s e  f o r   m y   r e g e x
W o r d s  c a n     b e    a r b i t r a r i l y   s p a c e d
```

gives:

```
This is a test case for my regex
Words can be arbitrarily spaced
```

Comment: You can also use `[a-zA-Z]` rather than `\a` to explicitly match English alphabetic words. Also depending on your regex tool `\1` might need to be replaced with `$1`

Comment: "s/" maybe the start mark of regex? Unfutunetly, I tried in R but didn't find the way to express start yet. The whole pattern involved in replacement.